# Securityd process uses 100% CPU when Mail app is open

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mail.app

I have a Macbook Air mid 2011 with OS X Yosemite. For a couple of weeks, I have a process, called Securityd, that runs and uses 100% of my processor, making it hot and noisy.

After some time, I discovered that the process is launching when I open the (native) Mail application. However this is not always happening. I am not sure of what makes it run, but it stops instantly when I quit the Mail app.

Do you have any idea of why this process is running, and how to fix it?

The Console.app shows nothing when I filter it with "Security". However, without filtering, when the process launch, I have this, which is looping infinitely :

```
25/05/15 09:57:39,166 icbaccountsd[1816]:  SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle 
SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle!! 418
25/05/15 09:57:39,531 icbaccountsd[1816]:  SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle!! 419
25/05/15 09:57:39,846 accountsd[1807]: Enter ShareKitAccountEnabler  - didChangeWithType - type=2 for account myemail@address.com (E0AAB503-12B6-4E2D-B519-10A05E4C7A2A).
25/05/15 09:57:39,846 accountsd[1807]: AIDA Notification plugin running
25/05/15 09:57:39,972 accountsd[1807]: Enter ShareKitAccountEnabler  - didChangeWithType - type=2 for account myemail@address.com (E0AAB503-12B6-4E2D-B519-10A05E4C7A2A).
25/05/15 09:57:39,973 accountsd[1807]: AIDA Notification plugin running
```

Comment: open Console.app and search `security`. (just `security` in order to include both `securityd` and `SecurityAgent`. Share ur output. It's probably an authorization problem with Mail.app or your mail accounts.

Comment: First, are you running the latest version of Yosemite, 10.10.3? Secondly, do you have any plugins in Mail?

Comment: Yes, I am running the latest version of Yosemite. And no, I don't think I have any plugin installed in Mail. Except maybe "Antidote" (I'm not sure it is a plugin), which is a spell checker for French language, but it is not running when the bug occurs, it only runs when I send an email. Also, the console was showing a plugin named "AIDA Notification".

Comment: Do you have a gmail account configured in your Mail app by chance?

Comment: If you do have a gmail account configured in Mail, navigate to: Mail>Preferences>Accounts>Gmail>Advanced and uncheck the box called "automatically detect and maintain accounts settings".

Comment: Yes I do. I will try this and let you know if the bug occurs again. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my advice is that u should unlink your email accounts and iCloud accounts from your MacBook Air. These unlink operation are to be done on MBA's side. Here is how I reached this conclusion:

1. `securityd` handles cryptographic operations on OS X. All processes communicate with `securityd` through `SecurityAgent`. That fact that these two are not throwing error in system log means something talking to them is the culprit.
2. `icbaccountsd` has ur email/icloud authorization info stored. To see what I mean, terminal:

   `/usr/libexec/icbaccountsd raw`

and you will see your addresses in the printout.

3. An error in the `icbaccountsd` doesn't necessarily mean a wrong password. It could also be a incorrect/corrupted public/private key. Or a formating error in the file (hence, the infinite loop).

So you should uncouple your emails from MBA and recouple them later. These are the measures you can take to do that, from safest to more drastic. You can do only one each time, add back your emails, and wait to see if it works. Or you can undertake all at once and add back. Needless to say, before re-adding, restart your laptop.

1. Deactivate all accounts under **System Preferences -> iCloud and Internet Accounts**. (This is probably too puny to work.)
2. Delete those accounts **System Preferences -> iCloud and Internet Accounts**.
3. Open Keychain app and delete any entry related to your email addresses and email servers. These entries can be passwords, keys, certificates, etc.
4. `open ~/Library/` and back up files in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/` and `~/Library/Mail/`. Delete the originals.

These would give you a machine free from any association with your emails. You many wonder if you should simply/also purge `/usr/libexec/icbaccountsd`. I won't recommend it til all else fails.